# Move Nice Menus to Just below the Title

Tags: drupal

I can't get the Nice Menu ( located on the top left) down to below the title bar. (i.e., just above the word "**Organize the information and make them accessible to the world**") in Drupal.

[http://lh5.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/SeDF5T6fBAI/AAAAAAAAErI/vEoQQPmC164/s400/site%20menu.jpg](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/BaViwySTq2lAuj-wAynBeA?feat=embedwebsite)

I tried to move the Nice Menu to `content` block in `admin/build/block`,  but it will then be located at the bottom, below the `content` block and above the powered by drupal sign. If I move it to `Header` then the above image is what I observed. There is no in between.

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You are being restricted by the particular theme that you are using, I believe. The theme template, by default, places any added blocks above the logo within the header and below any content.

My advice is to choose a different template (perhaps Zen) or learn how to manipulate the templates of a theme to get the results you want.

This book is pretty solid for learning how to theme:
[http://www.amazon.com/Drupal-Themes-Create-powerful-styling/dp/1847195660/ref=pd_sim_b_2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847195660)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal you need to edit theme template file themes/garland/page.tpl.php and move `<?php print $header; ?>` right before `<?php print $breadcrumb; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

As wrburgess supposed, this is a theme issue: Garland, which you are using, does not provide a mechanism to place block content above the main content area.

Other themes like Zen Classic (bundled with Zen), do. For themes including it, this region is usually called "content top".